# How to show $(T_k) \to \delta $ in the space of distribution $\mathcal{D'}(\mathbb{R}) $?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, distribution-theory

$f\in \mathcal{L}^{1}_{loc}(\Bbb{R}) $ and $\text{supp}(f) \subset [0, 1]$ and $\int_{0}^{1}f=1$

Consider a sequence $(f_k)_{k\in\Bbb{N}}$ where $f_k: \Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}$ defined by $$f_k(x) =kf(kx) $$

Calim :

1. $(f_k)\to \textbf{0} $ pointwise on $\Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.
2. $(T_k) \to \delta $ in the space of distribution $\mathcal{D'}(\mathbb{R}) $.

---

Fix $x\in \Bbb{R}$.
For $x<0$ , $\forall k\in\Bbb{N}$ we have $f_k(x) =0$.

For $x>0$ , $\exists N\in \Bbb{N}$ such that $Nx>1$ and hence $\forall k\in\Bbb{N} , k\ge N$ we have $f_k(x) =0$

Hence $f_k(x) \to 0$ on $ \Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$

---

$$T_k(\varphi(x)) =\int_{\Bbb{R} }f_k(x) \varphi(x) dx$$

where $\varphi\in \mathcal{D}(\Bbb{R}) =C_{c}^{\infty}(\Bbb{R}) $

To show : $T_k\to \delta$ in $\mathcal{D}'(\Bbb{R}) $ i.e $T_k(\varphi(x)) \to \delta(\varphi(x))=\varphi(0) $ on $\Bbb{R}$ for all $\varphi\in \mathcal{D}'(\Bbb{R}) $

$|T_k(\varphi(x))-\varphi(0) |\\=|\int_{0}^{1} f(t) \varphi(\frac{t}{k})dt-\int_{0}^{1} \varphi(0)f(t) dt |\\\le |\varphi(\frac{t}{k})-\varphi(0)|\int_{0}^{1}|f(t)| dt \\\le M |\varphi(\frac{t}{k})-\varphi(0)|<\epsilon$

By uniform continuity of $\varphi $ on $[0, 1]$.

Please help me to prove. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need support contained in $(0,1)$. With the present statement $f(x)\equiv 1$ on $[0,1]$ and $0$ for $x \notin [0,a]$ would be  a counter-example since $f_k(0)=k \to \infty$.

Comment: As a hint, note that $$T_k(\varphi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\varphi(x)kf(kx)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\varphi(u/k)f(u)\,\mathrm{d}u,$$ where we applied the substitution $u=kx$ in the last line.